# Draw rounded frame in UIView:drawRect, gets skewed after rotate/resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Okay... so I am getting the hang of iOS, have created a UIView with a combination of widgets (buttons, UITableViews) content and some rendering in drawRect.

The rendering is actually to draw a rounded rectangle within the UIView frame, with circular corners.  Then I add this view to my main view.

In the rotation animation, I change the position and aspect ratio of my UIView and called a layout method, and was pleased that it would smoothly change its shape and reposition its contents.... EXCEPT: something odd happens to my rendering... they sort of get squished, and my rounded corners are now elliptical/squished (even though the rendering code always makes circles) like the UIView applies a transform after the drawRect, but does;t re-render.

This is a very surprising effect, can someone give me a hint to what may be going on?  I want the rendering to be consistent and sensitive to the current rectangle.

EDIT: Added pictures.  The UIView onDraw renders framing and headers, and there are two UITableViews as children.  It starts up in portrait mode (figure 1) and looks fine.  When the parent view rotates I initiate an animation that changes the sizing of the subview to be suitable to landscape.  The sub UITableViews resize fine, but the rendering is now squished (Figure 2).

[image: Normal, rendered header and frame look good with UTTables]

[image: After animation (launched in rotation) resizes the view for landscape -- framing and header are squished]

Comment: Um... why was this down voted?

Comment: I don't know your requirement of drawing shapes but transform and drawing would not work together. I would recommend you to find a way to use image of shape you require and apply transformation/animation on it.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not explicitly applying a transformation.  All I'm doing is (1) implementing onDraw to inscribe a rounded rectangle within the view and (2) changing the shape of the view in the parent's view rotation animation. For some reason the rounded corners (which are an absolute 20 pixels horizontal and vertical) become ellipses after the rotation.  Why is that?

Comment: I *could* use an image of a rounded rectangle instead, but I'd have to slice that up into nine pieces and place them individually to keep it from getting stretched (i.e. because I want my corners to be *absolute* 20 pixels  rounded).  That would be a lot of work.  I'd also just like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Well, crap, this looked promising: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
Animate the views by changing the property values dynamically and redrawing the view. If this key is not present, the views are animated using a snapshot image.

Comment: A snapshot image would explain why my rendered graphics are getting squished instead of re-rendered, but this appeared to have no effect.

Comment: Really?  Downvoted with no reason and one seeming-answer but no follow-up?  This is a good/real question.  What the heck SO?

Comment: I'd like to help you but unable to understand your problem. If you can upload a sample project with same problem, it would be more helpful to understand the issue. BTW votedup

Comment: Thank you... on reflection I figured maybe I should provide some code that shows the problem.  It will take me a bit to boil it down but I will do so...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `contentMode` of your `UIView` to `Redraw`